# RequiredValidator error when bind selected value

Tags: gridview, drop-down-menu, telerik, requiredfieldvalidator

[image]

In edit mode of the grid, there is a dropdownlist for user to select.

For new record, it will select default message "Please select" 
 For existing record, it will databind the value from db to become selected value

I had added the requiredvalidator to make sure user had selected dropdownlist.
 it works when user create a new record, it will display error message if user not select.

but it had error when user edit the record, even though the dropdownlist had selected value.
 it still display error message

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/LRDB.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Admin_dictionary_BU.aspx.vb" Inherits="Admin_Admin_dictionary_BU" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
        <br />
        <strong><span class="style4">Business Unit</span><br /> </strong><br />

                                                            <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
                                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                                function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {
                                                                    sender.get_masterTableView().editItem(eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical());
                                                                }

                                                                function conformbox() {
                                                                    var con = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
                                                                    if (con == true) {
                                                                        return true;
                                                                    }
                                                                    else {
                                                                        return false;
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            </script>
                                                        </telerik:RadCodeBlock>

                                                        <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
                                                        </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
                                                            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid_BU" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" 
                                                            DataSourceID="LDS_BU" width="1000"  PageSize="15"
                                                                    GridLines="None" style="margin-top: 0px" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" 
                                                                    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                                                    ShowStatusBar="True" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True"
                                                            AllowAutomaticUpdates="True">
                                                                    <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
                                                                <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                                                    DataKeyNames="BU_ID" DataSourceID="LDS_BU" 
                                                                    AllowFilteringByColumn="False" AllowPaging="False" 
                                                                    CommandItemDisplay="Top" OverrideDataSourceControlSorting="true" >

                                                                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
                                                                    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" 
                                                                        Visible="True">
                                                                    </RowIndicatorColumn>
                                                                    <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" 
                                                                        Visible="True">
                                                                    </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                                                                    <Columns>
                                                                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
                                                                        </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU_ID" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter BU_ID column" HeaderText="BU_ID" 
                                                                            SortExpression="BU_ID" UniqueName="BU_ID" Visible="false">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU_Name" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter BU_Name column" HeaderText="BU Name" 
                                                                            SortExpression="BU_Name" UniqueName="BU_Name">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="shortname" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter shortname column" HeaderText="Shortname" 
                                                                            SortExpression="shortname" UniqueName="shortname">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="bu_addr" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter bu_addr column" HeaderText="Address" 
                                                                            SortExpression="bu_addr" UniqueName="bu_addr">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU_Tel" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter BU_Tel column" HeaderText="Telephone" 
                                                                            SortExpression="BU_Tel" UniqueName="BU_Tel">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU_TelPre" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter BU_TelPre column" HeaderText="Telephone Prefix" 
                                                                            SortExpression="BU_TelPre" UniqueName="BU_TelPre">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU_Fax" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter BU_Fax column" HeaderText="Fax No." 
                                                                            SortExpression="BU_Fax" UniqueName="BU_Fax">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU_FaxPre" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter BU_FaxPre column" HeaderText="Fax No. Prefix" 
                                                                            SortExpression="BU_FaxPre" UniqueName="BU_FaxPre">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU_SpeedDial" 
                                                                            FilterControlAltText="Filter BU_SpeedDial column" HeaderText="SpeedDial" 
                                                                            SortExpression="BU_SpeedDial" UniqueName="BU_SpeedDial">
                                                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                                                                    </Columns>
                                                                    <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
                                                                        <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column" 
                                                                            UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1">
                                                                        </EditColumn>
                                                                    <FormTemplate>

                                                        <table id="Table2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="50%" border="1" rules="none"
                                                            style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                            <tr class="EditFormHeader">
                                                            <td style="width:150px">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" Text="Company" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="rdl_company" runat="server" DataSourceID="LDS_Company"
                                                                 DataValueField="CompID" DataTextField="CompanyName" DefaultMessage="Please select..." >
                                                                </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rdl_company" 
                                                                     ErrorMessage="Please select a Company." ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lb" Text="BU Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_BU_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BU_Name") %>' TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="ShortName" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_shortname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shortname") %>' TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="Address" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_BU_addr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BU_addr") %>' TabIndex="2" Width="300" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" Text="Telephone" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_tel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bu_tel") %>' TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Please, enter valid phone number." ValidationExpression="\d+" ControlToValidate="tb_tel">
                                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text="Telephone Prefix" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_telpre" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bu_telpre") %>' TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Please, enter valid phone number." ValidationExpression="\d+" ControlToValidate="tb_telpre">
                                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" Text="Fax No." runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_fax" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bu_fax") %>' TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Please, enter valid phone number." ValidationExpression="\d+" ControlToValidate="tb_fax">
                                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" Text="Fax No. Prefix" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_faxpre" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bu_faxpre") %>' TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Please, enter valid phone number." ValidationExpression="\d+" ControlToValidate="tb_faxpre">
                                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr >
                                                            <td >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" Text="SpeedDial" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                            
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_speeddial" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bu_speeddial") %>' TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>                                                            
                                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                                                            ErrorMessage="Please, enter valid phone number." ValidationExpression="\d+" ControlToValidate="tb_speeddial">
                                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                            </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                               <tr>
                                                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# IIf((TypeOf(Container) is GridEditFormInsertItem), "Insert", "Update") %>'
                                                                        runat="server" CommandName='<%# IIf((TypeOf(Container) is GridEditFormInsertItem), "PerformInsert", "Update")%>' >
                                                                    </asp:Button>&nbsp;
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                                                        CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return conformbox();"></asp:Button>
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                                                        CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </FormTemplate>
                                                </EditFormSettings>
                                                                    <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
                                                                </MasterTableView>
                                                                <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
                                                                <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
                                                                </FilterMenu>

                                                        </telerik:RadGrid>

                                                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LDS_Company" 
                                                    runat="server" ContextTypeName="dcLRDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
                                                    TableName="db_Companies">
                                                </asp:LinqDataSource>

                                                        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LDS_BU" 
                                                    runat="server" ContextTypeName="dcLRDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
                                                    TableName="db_Business_units">
                                                </asp:LinqDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

code behind:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports Telerik.Web.UI.AsyncUpload
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing
Partial Class Admin_Admin_dictionary_BU
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub RadGrid_BU_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles RadGrid_BU.ItemCommand
        RadGrid_BU.MasterTableView.ClearEditItems()

        If e.CommandName = RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName Then   'Click Add New Record button            
            Dim editColumn As GridEditCommandColumn = CType(RadGrid_BU.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn"), GridEditCommandColumn)
            editColumn.Visible = False
        ElseIf (e.CommandName = RadGrid.RebindGridCommandName AndAlso e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted) Then
            e.Canceled = True
        Else
            Dim editColumn As GridEditCommandColumn = CType(RadGrid_BU.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn"), GridEditCommandColumn)
            If Not editColumn.Visible Then  'Click Cancel button (both Insert and Update mode)
                editColumn.Visible = True
            End If

            Dim ddlComp_id As RadDropDownList = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("rdl_company"), RadDropDownList)
            Dim txt_bu_name As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_bu_name"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_shortname As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_shortname"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_address As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_bu_addr"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_tel As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_tel"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_telpre As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_telpre"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_fax As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_fax"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_faxpre As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_faxpre"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_speeddial As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tb_speeddial"), TextBox)
            Dim dc As New dcLRDBDataContext

            If e.CommandName = "PerformInsert" Then

                Dim newRecord1 As New db_Business_unit
                dc.db_Business_units.InsertOnSubmit(newRecord1)
                newRecord1.CompID = ddlComp_id.SelectedValue
                newRecord1.BU_Name = txt_bu_name.Text

                newRecord1.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now
                newRecord1.LastUpdateBy = HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID")
                dc.SubmitChanges()

                RadGrid_BU.MasterTableView.ClearEditItems()
                RadGrid_BU.DataBind()

            ElseIf e.CommandName = "Update" Then
                Dim lid As Integer = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("BU_ID")

                Dim rec = (From p In dc.db_Business_units Where p.BU_ID = lid).FirstOrDefault
                If Not rec Is Nothing Then
                    rec.CompID = ddlComp_id.SelectedValue
                    rec.BU_Name = txt_bu_name.Text
                    rec.shortname = txt_shortname.Text
                    rec.BU_addr = txt_address.Text
                    rec.BU_Tel = txt_tel.Text
                    rec.BU_TelPre = txt_telpre.Text
                    rec.BU_Fax = txt_fax.Text
                    rec.BU_FaxPre = txt_faxpre.Text
                    rec.BU_SpeedDial = txt_speeddial.Text
                    rec.LastUpdateBy = HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID")
                    rec.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now
                    dc.SubmitChanges()
                End If

                RadGrid_BU.MasterTableView.ClearEditItems()
                RadGrid_BU.DataBind()
            ElseIf e.CommandName = "Delete" Then

                Dim lid As Integer = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("BU_ID")

                Dim chk_rec = (From a In dc.db_Countries Where a.BU_ID = lid).Count
                If chk_rec > 0 Then
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "MessageBox", "alert('Cannot delete because this dictionary had been used.');", True)
                Else

                    Dim rec2 = (From p In dc.db_Business_units Where p.BU_ID = lid).FirstOrDefault
                    If Not IsNothing(rec2) Then
                        dc.db_Business_units.DeleteOnSubmit(rec2)
                        dc.SubmitChanges()
                    End If
                End If





                RadGrid_BU.MasterTableView.ClearEditItems()
                RadGrid_BU.DataBind()
            End If

            dc.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadGrid_BU_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid_BU.ItemDataBound

        If (TypeOf e.Item Is GridEditableItem AndAlso e.Item.IsInEditMode) Then
            Dim item As GridEditableItem = e.Item
            Dim ddl As RadDropDownList = item.FindControl("rdl_company")
            ddl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "CompID").ToString
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to use validation group in RequiredFiedValidator

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator7" runat="server" ValidationGroup="drop" ControlToValidate="TextBox_UserName" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Username must contain atleast 6 characters!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[^\s]{6,30}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and then u have to use same validation gropu name on the button on which u want the validation to run,,,like this

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button_Add" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Width="40px" runat="server" ValidationGroup="drop" CommandName="Add" OnClick="Button_Add_Click" Text="Add" /><br />
```